# How to get RDP client to process the #@ key on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, macbook, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft's RDP client for logging in on my VBox Ubuntu that is running with VBoxHeadless. This works fine except that the #@ key does not seem to be recognized. Even the xev utility doesn't detect the keystroke.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I'd greatly appreciate your help!

FYI: I have a MacBook Pro (model 5,5) with a Belgian AZERTY keyboard.

Note: The #@ key is the one below the escape button in this picture:

[image]

Comment: The #@ key?  Not familiar with that.  Using Canadian Multistandard English QWERTY...

Comment: @menns: see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing ALT + 3 to get the # sign

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get the `@` sign.